# Since TensorflowJS can use the GPU via WebGL, why would I need an nVIDIA GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, gpgpu, tensorflow.js

So TensorFlowJS can use WebGL to do GPU computations and train deep learning models. Why isn't this more popular than using CUDA with an nVIDIA GPU? Most people just trying to prototype machine learning models would love to do so on their personal computer, but many of us resort to using expensive cloud services like AWS (although more recently Google Colab helps) for ML training if we don't have a computer with an nVIDIA GPU. I'm sure nVIDIA GPUs are faster than whatever GPU is in my Macbook, but probably any GPU will offer at least an order of magnitude speedup over even a fast CPU and allow for model prototyping, so why aren't well using WebGL GPGPU? There must be a catch I just don't know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebGL backend uses GLSL language to define functions and upload data as shaders - it "works", but you pay huge cost to compile GSLS and upload shaders: warmup time for semi-complex models is immense (we're talking about minutes just to startup). And then memory overhead is 100-200% of what model would normally need - and for larger models, you're GPU memory bound, you don't want to waste that.

Btw, actual inference time once model is warmed up and it fits in memory is ok using WebGL

On the other hand nVidia CUDA libraries provide direct access to GPU, so TF compiled to use them is always going to be much more efficient.

Unfortunately, not many GPU vendors provide libraries like CUDA, so most ML is done on nVidia GPUs

Then there is a next level when you're using TPU instead of GPU - then there is no WebGL to start with

Answer (score 0):

If I select WebGPU with the TFJS benchmark (https://tensorflow.github.io/tfjs/e2e/benchmarks/local-benchmark/index.html) it responds with "WebGPU is not supported. Please use Chrome Canary browser with flag "--enable-unsafe-webgpu" enabled...."

So when that's ready will it be competitive with CUDA? On my laptop it is about 15% faster than WebGL on that benchmark.

Comment: `WebGPU` definitely has less overhead than `WebGL`, but...Initial implementation is still `GLSL` based and it's going to take time to reimplement in new `WGSL`.  Unfortunately, `WGSL` is still text based representation that needs to be compiled before it can be used by GPU, so there will always be a startup delay.  But if done right, uploading uniforms should be much faster than uploading shaders with `GLSL`, so that should be better.  Which leaves memory handler - and unfortunately, that is mostly up to the browser, which means sub-par as browsers are notoriously lazy on garbage collection.